# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 doesn't create android project from the hybrid app

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an IBM MobileFirst Platform running on my eclipse and I have created a hello app with adding android environment to it. However, when I build the android environment, it just creates the native folder without creating the android project separately that I need to use to run using Android Studio. Is something wrong with my setup?

**Jave Version:**

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_121-b13 (en_US)
```

IBM MobileFirst Platform Version:

```
7.1.0.00.20170301-1645
```

Hello app project:

[image]

Comment: Change workspace of eclipse and create new Hello App then add android environment. This issue is not related to java version.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the android environment and select **Run As -> Build Android Environment** (This will create the Android project separately) or You can directly select **Run As -> Android Studio Project** and run the application using Android Studio (Make sure you have set the path to Android Studio installation in the preferences).

[image]

Comment: I for sure done that and also done "Run As > Android Studio Project". Log: Application 'hello' deployed successfully with environment 'android', But nothing happens. The "helloAndroidProject" is not getting created in my workspace, so running as Android Studio project gives no result nor it opens anything. What is your Java version?

Comment: My Java version is 1.7. What happens when you do a Build Android Environment?

Comment: Mine is 1.8. Nothing happens, it just indicates that it is built and deployed to MFP and that's it. I will try to install Java 1.7 and see if that will make a difference.

Comment: Yes change you compiler version and your installed jre to 1.7. Also verify what happens when you try deploying the app to the server. Open the console and verify.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if all the Android plugins are installed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFIb0.png)

I have seen the same issue but issue got resolved after
   1. All above android plugins are installed
   2. Oracle JDK8 made as default JDK for starting Android Plugin
   3. I have tried this using Eclipse version Kepler and Mars.